# Central moments of the wrapped normal distribution?

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, statistics

The wikipedia page defines the raw moments of the wrapped normal fairly succinctly:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution#Moments

However, I'm struggling to find any literature on the equivalent of central moments for the wrapped normal (and circular distributions in general).

Does the binomial transform still apply? If so, then I can derive the central moments using the raw moments.